# Does RavenDB tokenize and filter queries?

Tags: ravendb

If one defines a field in RavenDB for fulltext search, it uses an analyzer which tokenizes the field and does post processing ([source](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/indexes/using-analyzers)). If that field is now queried, what happens to the search term in the query? Is it also tokenized and post-processed? If yes, is it tokenized and post-processed by the same analyzer which is used during index time? Can the analyzer for indexing and for querying be different?

An example:

Collection:

```
{"Name": "xxxabcd", "@metadata": {"@collection": "Names"}}
{"Name": "yyyabcd", "@metadata": {"@collection": "Names"}}
```

Index:

```
from names in docs.Names
select new {
    names.Name
}
```

Activate `Indexing` on the Name field to `Search` and use the NGram analyzer (no idea how to do this in RQL). NGram creates 2-6 character long tokens out of the name ([source](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/indexes/using-analyzers#analyzers-that-tokenize-according-to-the-defined-number-of-characters)). So one token will be `abcd` which is shared by both documents.

Query:

```
from index "Names/ByName" 
where search(Name, "xxxabcd")
```

The query returns no search results.
If the search term would be post-processed to an NGram of `abcd`, it would return both documents, but it does not. So what happends to the search term `xxxabcd`?

I can not find any documentation how search terms on full-text fields are handled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the analyzer that is configured in the index definition is run both at indexing time and at query time (the same analyzer).

From:

https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/10-static-indexes-and-other-advanced-options#full-text-search-queries

> The search() method accepts the query string you're looking for and
> passes it to the analyzer for the specified field. It then compares
> the terms the analyzer returned with the terms already in the index,
> and if there's a match on any of them, it's considered to be a match
> for the query.

---

After investigation:
**NGram is an exception to the above rule.**

- You can use NGram to tokenize an index-field **at indexing time**.
- However, **at query time**, when making a full-text search over such field (`x.Name` in your case),
  the `StandardAnalyzer` is used to tokenize the searched term (`xxxabcd`) from the query predicate.

---

The default token length generated by the NGram analyzer is only `2-6 chars`.
So in your case, using your example, and the default NGram settings, the terms that are generated in the index from your 2 documents are:

[image]

Now, when you query with:

```
var result = session.Query<Index_With_NGram_Analyzer.indexEntry, Index_With_NGram_Analyzer>()
                    .Search(x => x.Name, "xxxabcd")
                    .OfType<myName>()
                    .ToList();
```

you will get **0** results because "xxxabcd" is Not passed via the NGram analyzer at query time,
but via the StandardAnalyzer instead.

Note again - this exception is only for the NGram analyzer.
For any other analyzer used - the **same** analyzer will be used at query time.

---

The way to go about this is **either**:

- Increase the NGram terms length
  (configuring `2-7 chars` will provide you with results for search term `xxxxabcd`).
  To modify the max NGram value, update the configuration key `Indexing.Analyzers.NGram.MaxGram`.
  [This article](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.0/csharp/server/configuration/configuration-options) explains how to modify a configuration key server-wide.
  You can use the Edit Index view in the Studio to modify this configuration just for a specific field in a specific index.
- Use another analyzer

---

For the sake of having a complete answer:

Index definition is:

```
public class Index_With_NGram_Analyzer : AbstractIndexCreationTask<myName>
{
    public class indexEntry
    {
        public string Name; 
    }
    
    public Index_With_NGram_Analyzer()
    {
        Map = companies => from c in companies
                           select new indexEntry()
                           {
                               Name = c.Name
                           };

        Index(r => r.Name, FieldIndexing.Search);
        Analyzers.Add(n => n.Name, nameof(NGramAnalyzer));
    }
}
```

```
public class myName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

Some other resources for FTS are:

**Full-Text Search**
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.0/csharp/client-api/session/querying/text-search/full-text-search

**Full-Text Search with Index**
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.0/csharp/indexes/querying/searching

**Demos**
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/text-search/fts-with-static-index-single-field
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/text-search/fts-with-static-index-multiple-fields

Comment: @SimonLang After investigation, I have edited the answer to the question. I am also deleting my previous comments here as they are not relevant anymore.
The above resolution will be added to RavenDB documentation.

Comment: Awesome!! That was exactly what I was looking for.
I think I will post a feature request so one can specify the analyzer to use for the search term. Because in some circumstances it makes sense to use NGram for indexing and for searching.

Comment: https://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-21864/Allow-to-specify-which-analyzer-will-be-used-at-query-time